# Visual Studio freezes log in

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

After I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1, I start to have problems with Visual Studio (2013 and 2015). 
At first Visual Studio freezes completely after a few seconds of open it. After several tests and break my head searching a solution, I discover that if I don't connect to visualstudioonline to access to my repositories, visual studio works properly.

I think I try to make several things, like:

- Erase an recreeate my user on Windows 10
- Reinstall both Visual Studio (on different order, just in case)
- Google it and try all the options of reset configuration of Visual Studio,
- No plugins installed, just standard installation of visual studio
  but any of these works for me.

anyone with the same problem, or better, anyone with a solution for this problem?

Thank you very much

Sorry for my English

Comment: Maybe a plugin is causing the slowdown, try disabling everyone.

Comment: No plugins installed, only the standard installation of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio while no project is loaded, click on your account on the top right, click account settings then click reenter account credentials.